# I want gave random rotation each cube on 3 dimention

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want gave random rotation each cube on 3 dimention following image. How do I ?

[image]
[image]

[upload my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZuKbFqQdjmwve10l0LDLqQh1hnXNemMk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it in another way.Because usually data is a list,that means it looks like 2D, so it's a little difficult to creat a real 3D data structure.I try to turn 3D into 2D, I just make a line with 1000dots,and place them as a cube.Down-left is the calculation to get each number of a three-digit number,a simple math.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried it. but  can't rotation each all cube as Independence.

Comment: pls upload your file.

Comment: I uploaded on other answer.

Comment: Sorry, deleted answer. but link guestion.

Comment: I managed to understand it.
I couldn't have come up with this on my own, so thank you so much.